# SQL Server - rule

Tags: sql-server

can anyone help me with my problem. I need to create a sql rule that will allow/limit the leader of a team to assess the workers. He must **once** in a month give grades (from 1 to 10) to each worker.

I am new at this, and till now i found nothing that would point me to the right direction.
Is the rule good option for this job?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how can an sql-server force a team leader to sit down and give assessments ?

Comment: not force him, but when team leader is trying to give grade to the worker, server should not allow this if the worker has already been given the grade this month...

Comment: you can add use an "update trigger" in the DB for that, but generally speaking, I agree with Tomtom - its better to implement such validations on the application level - not on the DB level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: just forget SQL Server here. Your question is akin to asking a form to do that - it is not the that decides that.

I am quite sure you dont expect your people to type SQL commands - so put the functionality into whatever PROGRAM you write, not the database server.

SQL "rules" are the wrong place for that. This is a workflow / business rule question.

> but when team leader is trying to give grade to the worker, server should not allow this if the 
>   worker has already been given the grade this month

Primary key with month / worker and you can not insert. Now start sitting down and WRITING a PROGRAM that handles the rest. No silver bullet repalcements for some programming here, sorry.